# Why did all the websites suddenly spread content over multiple pages?

Tags: website-design

Many websites these days are laying content over many pages. They would have a paragraph, then those stupid ads, then a paragraph, then more ads, then there's a next button. You have to go through this to read all of the stuff (or to get to the video if there is one, in which case all the text is bs and not needed). Why do websites do this?

Comment: Ad views, just that

Comment: Money,the driving force of anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reason of injecting Advertisements onto a page disrupting the experience and navigation is Ad Views leading to **Aggressive Monetization**.

Generally Ads are populated in the sidebar either to the left. However, once a website begins to starve out of money-hunger, they begin to take aggressive advertising on their website as a way to gain crazy monetization.

Needless to say, it's a Bad User Experience strategy.

A very popular pornography website has ads in the Scroll View before the User could navigate to the next page. This disrupts the user's flow and might get him to as well click on that ad, as well as viewing it.

Comment: It's all about money. Click bait titles lead to dull videos. Thanks. Accepted